# X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 2 at size 11 could not be loaded

Tags: xorg, r

I am on Ubuntu 13.10, with R version 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330) -- "Spring Dance" (64 bit).

It is a new install and when trying to plot I am getting above error message

> Error in title(main = "Test", line = -1) :
>
> X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 2 at size 11 could not be loaded

This is happening with X11(type="Xlib")

I looked around a bit, but could only find quite old threads. Prof. Ripley replied to a similar issue in 2013 with

> See ?X11 and the 'R Installation and Administration Manual'. You are dragging up ancient history (2002). The 'modern' X11 device (from 2007) uses cairographics and does not use X11 fonts. I suggest you take a look at how R was built and ensure that the cairo-based device is available. Further, for a long time most X11 installations have been from Xorg and not Xfree86, and do not generally have a config file.

That unfortunately doesn't help me, because I am using events:

```
setGraphicsEventHandlers(prompt="Click and drag to zoom, hit q to quit",
                           onMouseDown = dragmousedown,
                           onMouseUp = mouseup,
                           onKeybd = keydown)
eventEnv <- getGraphicsEventEnv()
getGraphicsEvent()
```

And those aren't supported on any other device. It is still working on my other machine, so I presume I just need to find fonts somewhere.

How do I install or generate those fonts on Ubuntu?

Comment: Just as a quick tip, I installed pretty much a gazillion fonts, only to realize that I needed to restart the computer as well - one of them fixed it. As an aside, maybe there is a way of loading new fonts without restart? That would be nice...

Comment: `xset fp rehash` tells the X server to rescan the directories in its font path for newly installed fonts (if the font was added to a directory already listed in the font path, and `mkfontdir` was run to update the `fonts.dir` files to list it).

Comment: I followed @user3002067 's suggestion and then ran `xset fp rehash` and then `mkfontdir` after. The issue persisted for me. Then I rebooted my system as suggested by @Cookie and then things started working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had the same problem with R4.0 on Ubuntu 18. Installing the packages “`gsfonts-x11`”, “`xfonts-base`”, “`xfonts-scalable`”, “`xfonts-100dpi`” and “`xfonts-75dpi`” fixed the problem for me.

Thanks to Pepe_Le_Pew for the [solution](https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/couldnt-find-font-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-10-iso8859-1/21619/3)

Comment: The solution proposed is in the sentence "Installing the packages..."  The link is merely attribution for the source of the information.

Answer (score 7):

I got this same issue using R in Ubuntu 14.04 specifically with the GGALLY package and the GGPAIRS function.  To recreate:

```
data(mtcars)
library(GGally)  
mtcars_subset <- mtcars[,c(2:11)]
ggpairs(mtcars_subset)

Error:
Warning message:  
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 16 could not be loaded
```

To fix this loaded the following and rebooted Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install t1-xfree86-nonfree ttf-xfree86-nonfree ttf-xfree86-nonfree-syriac xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi
```

Answer (score 6):

@Garini's answer solved this issue for me. And, to expand on @Garini's answer, you can add

`options(bitmapType="cairo")`

to your `~/.Rprofile` file to have this option enabled every time you load R without the need to remember to add it to each script.

Comment: This would've been nice under the said answer as a comment... But I get it, your reputation points.

Answer (score 5):

In ubuntu 18.04 the problem can appear again. It was enough, in my case to indicate the right bitmap.

```
options(bitmapType="cairo")
```