# Error in displaying graphics

Tags: display, r

I posted this error in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324093/error-in-grid-call) assuming it was an R problem. However, more and more I'm inclined to believe it is linux related error. The moment I press enter after typical plot command a small window pops up but empty and I get the error

`Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 11 could not be loaded`

I updated the system, installed the packages suggested in the mentioned post yet without any succuss. could you please help?

Thank you

**Edit:**

I already tried the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449578/x11-font-adobe-helvetica-s-s-d-face-2-at-size-11-could-no?rq=1) but it didn't work.

Comment: Excuse me sir, but  have you recently tried to download, build or debug any programs from the inter web

Comment: check me out > https://askubuntu.com/questions/449578/x11-font-adobe-helvetica-s-s-d-face-2-at-size-11-could-no?rq=1

Comment: In case someone passes by, the answer on my question on stackoverflow helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the bitmap to "cairo".

```
options(bitmapType="cairo")
```